# Locate closest domain controller using Java

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, domaincontroller

I have to connect Active Directory and fetch data based on the domain names. Using LDAP connection with Java.
For this I wanted to identify closest domain controller first.
Is there any method or API available in Java to identify closest domain controller based on domain name?

Comment: Look into https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/advantages/ease-of-use.html

Comment: Hi Susan,
Thanks for providing reference link.

Comment: The question in we will be provided with only domain name and port details(example.com and 389).
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://server.example.com:389/");

We have to identify the nearby server based on the domain name, so that we can pass it as ldap://server.example.com:389/ to create connection.

Answer (score 0):

To locate the domain controllers we can use LDAP queries(with site name) in java code.

Ex : srv _ldap._tcp.sitename._sites.example.net.local

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft's How domain controllers are located in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/how-domain-controllers-are-located), you can look up the LDAP SRV records of either of these forms:

- _ldap._tcp.domainname
- _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.domainname - this is karthik's sitename._sites example.

E.g. nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.company.int if your computer's FQDN is name.company.int.

At least where I'm testing, it doesn't seem to give them with a weight or priority to indicate the closest. I found a similar question on ServerFault, [Finding closest Domain Controller through LDAP](https://serverfault.com/questions/77947/finding-closest-domain-controller-through-ldap), that dives further into figuring out the closest.

See also [6.3.2.3 SRV Records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/c1987d42-1847-4cc9-acf7-aab2136d6952)